# Creating unique index via mongodb native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There is a code:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

const db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017/test')
db
  .then(
    async dataBase => {
      eduDb = dataBase.db('edu-service-accounts')
      const accounts = eduDb.collection('accounts')
      await accounts.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })
      accounts.insertOne({ email: '123' })
    }
  )
```

Code above creates an index, but that is no unique. I already read official docs for native mongoDB driver, but can't handle it.
And yes, I've deleted all old indexex before testing that code.

Can someone please show a code that really create an index with unique.
I mean not part of official doc, or something like that - I need code that works. 
NOTE: I tested that code with local db and mlab - the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Like the documentation says: `db.createIndex(collectionname, index[, options], callback)` the creation returns an index. Try to log the result of the callback. Maybe you are getting an error from the db.

Try something like:

```
 // your connection stuff
accounts.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true }, function(err, result) {
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);

   } else {
     console.log(result);
  } 
});
```

After that please provide us the logs.

Comment: I feel myself really stupid. When I launched code example above - it created an unique index.
I can't get why when I use this code:
https://gyazo.com/d57dba0ebdb6ee9dd9693d38779979fa
I don't get unique index. Even output is the same - there is no error.
But, created index is not unique:
https://gyazo.com/78c236b5f93ace768d4acdbcc0c58554
According documentation promises are available. What it can be?

Comment: I wrote my own promise and it works as expected:
https://gyazo.com/f83282644299320607904874c89827c1